# Referring to a class function by the unqualified name

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a class function like so:

```
class foo {
    // Private data needs to be accessed by bar
public:
    static int bar();
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Want to write bar() instead of foo::bar()
    bar();
}
```

`using` doesn't seem to work for importing a class member into global scope, and if `bar` is made a global function it won't be able to access private data. Is there a way `bar` can be made accessible in global scope by the unqualified name?

Comment: The only way to call a `static` member function is by qualifying it with the class name `foo::bar()`. You need to access a `static` member function or just any member function? Your emphasis seems to be more towards avoiding the qualification rather than selecting the method to be `static` or member or freestanding depending on your requirement.

Comment: A `static` member function specifically. Maybe I can make it a `friend` global function instead.

Comment: I believe you would know that You cannot access the class's non-static data members inside the static method, so bothering about access specification and friendship for such an method has most likely no meaning.

Comment: Sure you can, if you have a pointer to an object of the class, you just don't have an implicit `this` pointer.

Comment: Sure, but your method has no parameters neither does your example code shows any globals so you don't have an object instance to use in the `static` method.The scenario doesn't apply to your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's what `friend`s are for.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtGF2m102Wg)

```
class foo {
    int i;
    // Private data needs to be accessed by bar
public:
    friend int bar(foo);
};

int bar(foo f) {
    return f.i = 3;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo g;
    // Want to write bar() instead of foo::bar()
    bar(g);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int bar()
{
    return foo::bar(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `foo::bar` *somewhere*, but can hide it in a function.

```
int bar()
{ return foo::bar(); }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     // Want to write bar() instead of foo::bar()
     bar();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Factor the static stuff in `foo` out, since it doesn't belong in a class anyway. The only functional difference between a class and a namespace is that you can instantiate a class. Since you obviously don't need that (as you're using static member functions) you might just as well change `foo` into this:

```
namespace foo {
    class fooData { // optional, if you must hide the private data
      friend int bar();
      // Private data needs to be accessed by bar
    };
    int bar();
};

using foo::bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, stub global function. Or a macro:

```
#define bar foo::bar
```

There is no real way of importing into namespace, like C# `using`.